# Lat/long columns into point column in PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a simple postgres database with 4-5 columns including one latitude and one longitude column. I want to have an additional postGIS point column, but are at loss how I construct this new column using the two excisting latitude and longitude columns.

```
Table1
a  |  b  |  c | latitude | longitude | location(point column)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And I found the answer myself. First of all, my latitude and longitude columns was varchar, so I had to convert them to use the ST_Makepoint function. Note that I use WSG4326 coordinates in this code, change accordingly.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN location GEOMETRY(point, 4326);
UPDATE table1 SET location = ST_SETSRID(ST_MakePoint(cast(longitude as float), cast(latitude as float)),4326);
```

Comment: You answer is right, but I wouldn't simply assume that the coordinates used are encoded with WGS84. Maybe mention in your answer that one needs to know which SRS is being used before playing with geometries. I agree that in most cases WGS84 is used, but it can create a lot of confusion if not ;) cheers

Comment: Thank you @JimJones - good point. Have had my fair share of weird results by mistakenly assuming that.